# How to remove the padding in table border?

Tags: html

I want no padding in the border
like this table
[image]

but my table is here
[image]

How can I make that table?

This is my HTML code

```html
<table border="2">
  <th>Location</th>
  <th>Topic</th>
  <tr>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Javascript & JQuery</td>
    <td>HTML & CSS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've set the padding to 0 but, It was same

Comment: `td,th { padding:0; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `border-spacing`. Check my code below:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border="2">
  <th>Location</th>
  <th>Topic</th>
  <tr>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Javascript & JQuery</td>
    <td>HTML & CSS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse; /* This removes spacing between table cells */
      border: 2px solid black;    /* Set the border style and width */
      width: 100%;                /* Make the table fill its container */
    }
    th, td {
      border: 2px solid black;    /* Set the border style and width for cells */
      padding: 0;                 /* Remove padding inside cells */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Topic</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Javascript & JQuery</td>
    <td>HTML & CSS</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: TRy this one and check